Is there a widely accepted approach to decomposing government bond yields across different maturities, and if so, what are the main components?
I'm wondering if there is a standard framework or methodology to decompose government bond yields across various maturities (e.g., short-, medium-, and long-term). Specifically, I’m interested in understanding what the main components are in terms of the yield for bonds of different maturities.
Are there any widely accepted models or approaches used in the finance fields to break down these yields? If so, how do they decompose government bond yields, and does this vary by maturity?

I'm not sure what you mean by "decomposing". They do publish a yield curve (and the methodologies that they use to calculate it based on the market prices of bonds of different maturities.

@DStanley, what I meant by decomposing is something akin to this: "In simple terms, long-term yields could be seen as a stack of short-term yields, inflation forecasts, and economic outlook, while short-term yields may be indicative of current market liquidity."
